# How do I run a function before my app crashes? iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm developing an iOS application and I want to get a specific function to run before my app crashes (if it ever does) as a security measure.

- Is it possible to 100% of the time, run a function whenever the app is about to crash?
- If not, in which situations can I and can't I get the function to run.  I.e. it can run when it's an out of memory crash, but it can't run if it's a null reference exception for example.

Specifically, I am using Betfair's API and if the app crashes I want the app to first cancel all bets with Betfair before closing the application.  I realise that this may in fact be impossible due to the nature of a crash stopping the entire app.

I'm using Xamarin and C# to develop the app (in case that matters!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and `signal` to catch most errors.

I've flagged a dupe answer which should have more details and discusses some edge cases that won't be caught without additional effort.

I don't know if C# changes the equation too dramatically. I haven't experimented with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

And you're using

```
 try
 {
 }
catch(Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

around what could go wrong?

Comment: Thanks Dylan.  Yes I was using these, I just wanted to make sure that it would run the correct function if I had missed a try/catch somewhere.